# How to prevent __init__? Python

Tags: python, function

Here is my code:

```
class Game_Events(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print "Done"

    def thing(self):
        print "thing"

    def test(self):
        print "test"
        GE = Game_Events()
        GE.thing()

GE = Game_Events()
GE.test()
```

When I run it I get:

```
Done
test
Done
thing
```

Which mean it ran `__init__` again when I called GE.thing().
But I don't what it to run again only once at the beginning and then never again.

How can I do this?

Comment: It ran again when you did `GE.test()` since inside `test` you create a new `Game_Events` with `GE = Game_Events()`.

Comment: The second `Done` is for `GE = Game_Events()` in `test` function , what you excepted to out from this?

Comment: What is the purpose of creating another `Game_Events()` object inside of `test()`?

Comment: Should this be closed? This is one of those questions of which I am not convinced the answer will be helpful to anyone else in the future.

Comment: __init__() is constructor. It executes whenever an instance of your class is created.

Comment: @shive nope, `__new__` is the constructor. `__init__` is the _initialiser_. And yes, I am fun at parties. :)

Comment: @N.Wouda agreed should be closed.

Comment: @N.Wouda: I call BS. In C++, Java, C#, Javascript, etc., a constructor starts out with an uninitialized object and initializes it. There is no convention saying a constructor is responsible for allocating the object as well. `__init__` is a constructor, and `__new__` is like a hybrid `operator new`-constructor thing.

Answer (score 5):

You are creating another `Game_Event` object in test. Use the existing class, by using the `self` variable, as follows.

```
class Game_Events(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print "Done"

    def thing(self):
        print "thing"

    def test(self):
        print "test"
        self.thing()
```